# Adding a class on a map items one by one, but how can I remove it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, class, onclick

My goal is to add a class to a single item in a items map and close it with another button.
The class is added when clicking on the item, but I can't close it.

I tried setActive(false) on the close button, but the class "active" is still here.

```
const lightbox = () => {

    const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
    {DataGroups.map((DataGroups, idx) => {
    return (
        <div key={DataGroups.id}>
            <div onClick={() => { setActive(DataGroups) }} className={`groups-card rounded-mainRadius ${active == DataGroups ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                <div className="groups-card-lightbox">
                    <h2>{DataGroups.title}</h2>
                    <p className="groups-card-description">
                        {DataGroups.description}
                    </p>
                    <div onClick={() => { setActive(false) } } className="font-bold hover:text-green">
                        Close the lightbox
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 className="groups-card-title">{DataGroups.title}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue comes from event propagation. Because your close item is a child of your event which set the active class, you're setting your state to false and immediately to DataGroups. Resulting that your condition is always `true`

So you should do:

```
<div onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation(); // and/or e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    setActive(null) 
  }
}>
```

Comment: I missed this! This is true. Though take also my suggestions to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a problem with this condition:

```
${active == DataGroups ? 'active' : ''}
```

Your state item `active` has 3 possible values, which is confusing. It is initially `null`, then it is `DataGroups` and then it is `false`.

I think you are trying to have it so that only one datagroup is "active" at a given time. You should likely change this state item to contain just the `id` of the data group which is active. And additionally use `null` to indicate nothing is active. Then change the condition to check the id of the datagroup being currently iterated against the one which is stored inside of `active`.

There is some additional confusion here where you have:

```
DataGroups.map((DataGroups, idx) => {
```

You should name the single datagroup uniquely, and not name it the same as the whole set. So this is easier to understand and less confusing by doing:

```
DataGroups.map((DataGroup, idx) => {
```

I also renamed `active` to `activeId` for sake of clarity.

Finally and crucially, every data group will need a unique ID. You can not reuse the same ID between entries. This is probably already the case but just to reiterate -- that is crucial.

```
const lightbox = () => {
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      {DataGroups.map((DataGroup, idx) => {
        return (
          <div key={DataGroup.id}>
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                setActiveId(DataGroup.id);
              }}
              className={`groups-card rounded-mainRadius ${
                activeId === DataGroup.id ? "active" : ""
              }`}
            >
              <div className="groups-card-lightbox">
                <h2>{DataGroup.title}</h2>
                <p className="groups-card-description">
                  {DataGroup.description}
                </p>
                <div
                  onClick={() => {
                    setActiveId(null);
                  }}
                  className="font-bold hover:text-green"
                >
                  Close the lightbox
                </div>
              </div>
              <h2 className="groups-card-title">{DataGroup.title}</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you ! Yes I understand now, I used to give the same name for the list and the item, but giving 'DataGroup' for the item is clearer.

And yes, Each item has a different id, I could fix this with the message in the console.

Thank you for your time :)  I'm actually learning a lot !